# How ought I store localised values in a DRY and database efficient way - Ruby on Rails / i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, internationalization, rails-i18n

What is the recommended approach to maintaining multi-language values within an ActiveRecord model.

I am looking into upgrading our database schema and Object Models to allow for widespread internationalisation of many of the values, and I am weighing up various ways to do this.

The standard [rails-i18n system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) is largely silent on this, although it offers powerful tools for internationalising field and model names, in addition to the text within views.

The [R18n gem](https://github.com/ai/r18n) allows you to overload your database with columns that store the localised strings, and which present the correct value depending on the locale.  This presents a couple of problems.

Say we are talking about a model `Sport` — database table `sports`. We need to be able to search for `Sport.where(name: 'soccer')` even though in the UK they call it 'football', so the query becomes `scope :with_name ->(n){ where("name_en_GB = ? OR name_en_AU = ?", n, n) }`.

If we want to add another locale we need to both update the schema, and update any such queries on that schema. A rather brittle solution.

Another solution I've seen is to maintain a separate `SportLocale` model and associated `sport_locales` table, that holds the name and locale.

Assuming

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locales
end

class SportLocale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sport
end
```

Then to find the right sport you'd do something like

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locales, class_name: "SportLocale"
  self.with_name(n)
    SportLocale.where(name: n, locale: I18n.locale).first.try(:sport)
  end
end
```

This is fine if `Sport` is your only localised model but when you start adding all the other models it becomes a bit crazy, with each of them needing an associated *Locale model.  Not the `DRY`est of solutions either.

I'd like a solution that allows

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Localised
  localised_field :name
end
```

and magically `Sport.where(name: 'football')` will find the right sport.

Is there any such system out there already, or would I have to build it myself?
How are other projects dealing with this sort of problem?

Comment: Would you be able to please edit your question to elaborate *why* you want to deal with the i18n of model properties at the model/schema level and not at the view level (where I think at least most Rails devs would expect it to be handled).  Also, would you also be able to please provide a source for the `SportLocale` solution you say you have seen before, if you have one (this question is the first I've seen such a proposed solution).

Comment: Paul the reason is that the data is not static but will be built-up over time as more items are added to the system. The views need to be able to display `current_sport.name` and return the correctly localised name for that sport. I can't provide the source for the `*Locale` model approach as it's something I have seen in a proprietary codebase. Indeed the one I am seeking to redesign now.

Answer (score 3):

The `i18n` Ruby gem (which is used by Rails) is mostly useful for static translations, i.e. translations which can be considered part of the code (just like you'd consider static, hardcoded strings in your views part of the code). These are, most of the time, stored in static YAML files, so they'd change at deploy time.

I don't know about the current version of `R18n`. When I once looked at it years ago it provided an alternative way to do similar things (with a different syntax and slightly different features).

Translating model data is a different task. [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) is maybe the most widely used solution for it, but there are lots of other solutions. Unless you're feeling adventurous I'd recommend to use a mature solution, translating data (and integrating with ActiveRecord) can be hairy when it comes to more complicated usecases.

Comment: I have two concerns re `Globalize`. One is that it's got a lot of outstanding PRs and issues and seems unmaintained for quite a while.  Two is there is nothing in the docs about how I might run queries against localised fields.  We are using Postgres here so `hstore_translate` seems more suitable and more up-to-date. I'd need to do some experiments next sprint.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem you are trying to solve, you may get something out of the [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) gem.

It hides away the translation tables you need, but it can provide a standard for mapping of 'soccer' [en-au] to 'football' [en-uk] that you might be able to interrogate for the translated attribute values you're looking for.

Comment: That looks ideal. I'll check it out further and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking [`hstore_translate`](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate) will better suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store the I18n localization key associated to your sport and search for it?

To display the name to the user, just use that key against the user's current locale.

Comment: Because I don't know all the values in advance. The data for a wide range of locales will be populated over time.